# Visual Studio 2013 Enable package restore value storage location

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget-package-restore

All I'm trying to do is figure out where (if anywhere) the setting for "Enable NuGet Package Restore" is stored.  The reason I ask is because my solution will reappear with this option once once you reopen it.  I click this option, save, and see that this option disappears.  OK great!  It looks like something has saved and it should remember that this has been clicked before so it's not on the menu anymore.  Not, true.  At least for me, when I reopen the sln, the menu option reappears.  I want to figure out where this value is saved, hopefully in some text file I can edit.

Any takers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find the answer to this.  It's actually in your .nuget Folder within NuGet.targets.  Look for this tag and set it to true like below:

`<!-- Enable the restore command to run before builds -->
<RestorePackages Condition="  '$(RestorePackages)' == '' ">true</RestorePackages>`